# Making a dynamic array with a sort and shuffle method, neither method is working right

Tags: java, arrays

For a Java class we have to make a Dynamic array. Cannot use arraylist.

Here is where I define the class

```
public class DynamicArray {

    private int array[];
    private int size;
```

Here is the called constructor:

```
/**
 * DynamicArray     copies the array
 * @param obj 
 */
public DynamicArray(DynamicArray obj) {
    array = obj.toArray();
    size = obj.getSize();
}
```

Under the main method, here is where I create the new array object and try to sort and shuffle (as well as a few of the other methods, but those are working):

```
   /**
    * Calling the copy constructor, which calls the toArray method
    * Calling get method
    * Calling indexOfMethod
    * Calling findMax
    * Calling findMin
    * Calling shuffle
    */

   DynamicArray array3 = new DynamicArray(array2);
   array3.push(100);
   array3.push(150);
   array3.push(100);
   System.out.println(array3);
   array3.pop();
   System.out.println(array3);
   System.out.println("This number is at index 5: " + array3.get(5));
   System.out.println("The number 100 first appears at index: " + array3.indexOf(100));
   System.out.println("The highest number is: " + array3.findMax());
   System.out.println("The lowest number is: " + array3.findMin());
   System.out.println(array3);
   array3.shuffle();
   System.out.println(array3);
   array3.sort(array3.toArray());
```

The toArray method is this:

```
/**
 * toArray      accessor returns the array
 * @return 
 */
public int[] toArray() {
    int arrayCopy[] = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        arrayCopy[i] = array[i];
    }

    return arrayCopy;
}
```

And the sort and shuffle methods are this:

```
/**
 * isEmpty      returns size = 0 is array is empty
 * @return 0 if empty
 */

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

/**
 * sort     sorts the numbers in the array
 */

public void sort(int [] array) {
    int lastPos;
    int index;
    int newNum;

    for (lastPos = array.length - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {
        for (index = 0; index <= lastPos - 1; index++) {
            if (array[index] > array[index + 1]) {
                newNum = array[index];
                array[index] = array[index + 1];
                array[index + 1] = newNum;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * shuffle      shuffles the array
 */
 public void shuffle() {
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int index = r.nextInt(i);
        int tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[index];
        array[index] = tmp;
    }
}
```

The output for sort has 0's in it:

0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 150, 0, 2,

And shuffle is not changing anything.

These were created with help in the tutoring lab and I've compared them to recommendations online.

What's going on?

Updated:

Here's the array2:

```
       /**
        * Calling constructor with parameter
        * also calling push to add items to the array
        */

       DynamicArray array2 = new DynamicArray(5);
       array2.push(4);
       array2.push(10);
       array2.push(15);
       array2.push(18);
       array2.push(2);
       array2.push(25);
       System.out.println("Size is: " + array2.getSize());
       array2.push(20);
       System.out.println("Size is: " + array2.getSize());
       System.out.println(array2);
```

Here's getSize()

```
/**
 * getSize     gets size of the array
 * @return size
 */
public int getSize() {
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide information how *array2* is instantinated? It is starting point for the algorithm.

*getSize()* implementation would be useful also.

For now you can check sorting algorithms here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/
e.g. Bubble sort is quite easy to understand and implement.

For shuffling implementation you can check:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsShuffle/article.html